# Insert a list, element by element, into the elements of an array of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of arrays:

```
parameters = [np.array([ 2.1e-04, -8.3e-03, 9.8e-01]), np.array([ 5.5e-04, 1.2e-01, 9.9e-01]), ...]
```

whose length is:

```
print len(parameters)

100
```

If we label the elements of `parameters` as `parameters[i][j]`:

it is then  possible to access each number, i.e. `print parameters[1][2]` gives `0.99`

I also have an array:

```
 temperatures = [110.51, 1618.079, ...]
```

whose length is also `100`:

```
print len(temperatures)

100
```

Let the elements of `temperatures` be `k`:

I would like to insert each `k`th element of `temperatures` into each `i`th element of `parameters`, in order to obtain `final`:

```
final = [np.array([ 2.1e-04, -8.3e-03, 9.8e-01, 110.51]), np.array([ 5.5e-04, 1.2e-01, 9.9e-01, 1618.079]), ...]
```

I have tried to make something like a `zip` loop:

`for i,j in zip(parameters, valid_temperatures):
   final = parameters[2][i].append(valid_temperatures[j])`

but this does not work. I would appreciate if you could help me.

**EDIT**: Based on @hpaulj answer:

If you run **Solution 1**:

```
 parameters = [np.array([ 2.1e-04, -8.3e-03, 9.8e-01]), np.array([ 5.5e-04, 1.2e-01, 9.9e-01])]
 temperatures = [110.51, 1618.079]

     for i,(arr,t) in enumerate(zip(parameters,temperatures)):
     parameters[i] = np.append(arr,t)

 print parameters
```

It gives:

```
 [array([  2.10000000e-04,  -8.30000000e-03,   9.80000000e-01,
     1.10510000e+02]), array([  5.50000000e-04,   1.20000000e-01,   9.90000000e-01,
     1.61807900e+03])]
```

which is the desired output.

In addition, **Solution 2**:

```
parameters = [np.array([ 2.1e-04, -8.3e-03, 9.8e-01]), np.array([ 5.5e-04, 1.2e-01, 9.9e-01])]
temperatures = [110.51, 1618.079]

parameters = [np.append(arr,t) for arr, t in zip(parameters,temperatures)]

print parameters
```

also gives the desired output.

As opposed to **Solution 1**, **Solution 2** doesn't use the `i`th `enumerate` index. Therefore, if I just split **Solution 2**'s `[np.append ... for arr ]` syntax the following way:

```
 parameters = [np.array([ 2.1e-04, -8.3e-03, 9.8e-01]), np.array([ 5.5e-04, 1.2e-01, 9.9e-01])]
 temperatures = [110.51, 1618.079]

 for arr, t in zip(parameters,temperatures):
   parameters = np.append(arr,t)   

 print parameters
```

The output contains only the last iteration, and not in an "array-format":

```
 [  5.50000000e-04   1.20000000e-01   9.90000000e-01   1.61807900e+03]
```

How would it be possible to make this to work, by printing all the iterations ?
Thanks

Comment: You have a *list* of arrays... and then a *list* of temperatures.

Comment: probably `parameters[i] = parameters[i].append(temperatures[i])`. this should append `i`th element of `temperatures` to `i`th element in `parameters`

Comment: @ArturRychlewicz No, it won't, because `list != np.array`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a list of arrays, plus another list or array:

```
In [656]: parameters = [np.array([1,2,3]) for _ in range(5)]
In [657]: temps=np.arange(5)
```

to combine them just iterate through (a list comprehension works fine for that), and perform a `concatenate` (array append) for each pair.

```
In [659]: [np.concatenate((arr,[t])) for arr, t in zip(parameters, temps)]
Out[659]: 
[array([1, 2, 3, 0]),
 array([1, 2, 3, 1]),
 array([1, 2, 3, 2]),
 array([1, 2, 3, 3]),
 array([1, 2, 3, 4])]
```

the use `append` saves us two pairs of `[]`, otherwise it is the same:

```
 [np.append(arr,t) for arr, t in zip(parameters,temps)]
```

A clean 'in-place' version:

```
for i,(arr,t) in enumerate(zip(parameters,temps)):
    parameters[i] = np.append(arr,t)
```

================

If the subarrays are all the same length, you could turn `parameters` into a 2d array, and concatenate the `temps`:

```
In [663]: np.hstack((np.vstack(parameters),temps[:,None]))
Out[663]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 0],
       [1, 2, 3, 1],
       [1, 2, 3, 2],
       [1, 2, 3, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

Comment: Well, you are creating new arrays anyway. It would serve to point out that this is a poor use of `numpy` data structures.

Comment: The inefficiency in time isn't really due to the list comprehension but the fact that `np.array` s are being used where probably plain Python `list` is the way to go.

Comment: If you are starting with a list, it is often faster to stick with list operations.  Creating an array has a substantial overhead.  We have to perform timings on realistic data to tell which is faster.

Comment: Right, I was responding to the other person who deleted their comment. "appending" to an array will almost certainly be slower, thought

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you very much for your three suggestions: 1) `concatenate`, 2) `np.append` (both in one line and in a `for loop`) and 3) `hstack`. Sorry for the 20h delay on the answer, but I have been digging hard into all these solutions. I have tried to understand all the syntax and how all these functions behave. First starting with `enumerate`, followed by `zip`, and then how to combine these two. I have tried to extrapolate the  `[np.append(arr,t) for arr, t in zip(parameters,temperatures)]` solution to the clean 'in-place' solution: Please see the **EDIT**